# Connections is not available sometimes in c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I am working on a web project in which i have used c3p0 in web services.I have configured the following pararamters in hibernate.cfg.xml file.But even though i have given max_size is 10000 and idle test period is 30 ,Sometimes mysql server is not providing another connection to db.So the website is getting load and load till i restart my server.And my in log shows "too many conection are opened".What i miss in the following configuration.Please help me out

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">5000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">500</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have a Connection leak. A gigantic pool size won't really help with that. Please see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

## Appendix: Robust Resource Cleanup idiom

It's best when you can to use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). But if you are working with an older version of Java (pre Java 7), or with resources that don't implement `AutoCloseable` you may still have to revert to this kind of thing.

```
Connection c     = null;
OtherResource or = null;

try
{
   c  = cpds.getConnection();
   or = getOtherResource()

   // do stuff
   // ...
}
finally
{
  try { if (or != null) or.close(); }
  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

  try { if (c != null) c.close(); }
  catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Note that the finally clause will definitely be executed if the Connection is acquired, and there is a best-attempt close() of each resource: If `or`
fails to close(), that Exception won't prevent the attempt to close() the
Connection.

You have to be very careful. As Keynes famously put it, there's many a slip 'twixt the cup and the lip.

Comment: Yeah i understand but i am closing each and every session which is opened in dao layer like  sessionobj.clear();
   sessionobj.flush();
   sessionobj.close();

Comment: so you think. are you using Java 7+ try-with-resources or else the cumbersome, old-fashioned robust resource cleanup idiom? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784674/spring-c3p0-postgres/11786683#11786683 if you use try parameters described at the link above, i suspect that you will see that you are not. i could be wrong! but just closing sessions after use isn't enough. exceptions happen.

Comment: My goto robust-resource-cleanup link seems to have expired, I've updated the post with an explanation (scraped from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/c3p0/mailman/c3p0-users/?viewmonth=200811)).