# closed connections in c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I´m starting with Hibernate.
Since I read that I need to configure the pool connection I start using C3P0

everything is fine, but when I reach the maximum connections the application freezes, I have to close the application and start it again.

this is my C3P0 part in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>  
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
```

in my function when I save the object I close the session.

```html
   

 public void Save item(Item item)throws Exception{    
            try{          
            SessionFactory sf= NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Session session;
            session = sf.openSession();
            Transaction tx= session.beginTransaction(); 
            session.save(item); 
            tx.commit();
            session.close();          
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                throw new Exception(ex);
            }
        }
```

if I check the connections in MySql I see that all the connections are sleep, but the application freezes.

what am I missing here?

Comment: How do you mean freezes?  Is it hanging in any particular line of code ?

Comment: when I click on the button to save the object the application stop working. (not responding state).
if I check the connection I see that I reach the max connections permitted. that´s why (I think )the application freeze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reliably `close()`ing Connections (wrapped within Sessions), so they leak. Consider what happens when an Exception occurs.

Either use Java 7+ try-with-resources, if Session supports that, or use the old robust cleanup idiom, see the [Appendix to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821464/connections-is-not-available-sometimes-in-c3p0).

If you fix this and are still experiencing a Connection leak, c3p0 has [configuration parameters](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients) to help you track down the leak.